# Shopify API error when creating a Draft Order

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Getting an error when making an API call to create a custom order in Shopify store. The error message I am receiving is **{"errors":{"base":["Add at least 1 product"]}}**

From reading their documentation, I am sending the required parameters. Not sure if this is a formatting issue.

This is their code

```
curl -d '{"draft_order":{"line_items":[{"title":"Custom Tee","price":"20.00","quantity":2}],"customer":{"id":207119551},"use_customer_default_address":true}}' \
-X POST "https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/draft_orders.json" \
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This is my code:

```
$shop = "xxxxxx.myshopify.com";
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$query = array(
    "Content-type" => "application/json"
);

$draft_param = array(
        "draft_order" =>array(
            "line-items" => array(
                "title" => "Toy Ball",
                "price" => "10.00",
                "quantity" => 1,
                "custom" => true,
                ),
            "customer" => array(
                "id" => 1655457444313,
                ),
            "use_customer_default_address" => true          
        )
    )
    ;

$draftorder = shopify_call($token, "$shop", "/admin/api/2023-07/draft_orders.json", 
$draft_param, 'POST');
```